# \footcite command generates errors

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am trying to use BibTeX to generate references for a paper. I can just about get it to cite as I want using the `\cite` command. But I would like the references to be below the text. I have attempted to use the `\footcite` command, but this produces the following error "! Undefined control sequence. l.74 ...Generic text.\footcite
[{pp.~20-1.}]{ref... The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type`I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined."

In abbreviated form my code is like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}  
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\setlength\footnotemargin{10pt}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\begin{document}
Generic text.\footcite{ref}
\bibliography{QPbib}
\end{document}
```

Bib is like this:

```
@article{ref,
Author = {Garth Marenghi},
Date-Added = {2017-09-07 18:04:40 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2017-09-07 18:05:14 +0000},
Journal = {Expertise},
Number = {4},
Pages = {208},
Title = {Darkplace},
Volume = {38},
Year = {1988}}
```

(I have included the footnote margin commands in case these are part of what is generating the problem. Likewise for `\baselinestretch`. I was originally using the `setspace` package but this generated errors that I will be asking about in a separate question.)

Thank you for your help and apologies for my no doubt callow errors.

Comment: Welcome! 'Callow errors'?

Comment: `apacite` doesn't provide `\footcite` and it is not a core LaTeX macro. Hence, it is not defined, which is why LaTeX tells you that. Note: I'm guessing here. You didn't actually include the crucial part of the error message which tells you *which* sequence is undefined and on which line it occurs. Please always include the full text of error messages.

Comment: You could define it yourself to do whatever you want it to do. Or you could use a package or whatever which provides the macro. (Biblatex certainly does, but that means switching away from BibTeX which you may not wish to do.)

Comment: Note that you can either use one of the standard `.bib`s when asking a question which needs one or you need to include the require entry or entries, along with your `.tex` example in order for people to compile the code.

Comment: Thank you! I think the missing error message is one such callow mistake. I'll try and edit in, I think I understand what is missing. Likewise for `.bib`.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I would define `\footcite`? I've seen one way of doing it in answer to another question, but it was intended for biblatex and I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Well, what were you wanting it to do? Do you just want it to put a citation in a footnote? Or do you want it to use a different format in a footnote?

Comment: Thanks for adding the information. One tiny thing: the line breaks in error messages are crucial, so it is best to copy them and format them as code blocks, so you retain the breaks. Then it is obvious which control sequence is at the end of the top line of the error message, for example, which is what the error is telling us to look for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possible way you might define `\footcite`. If you want something different, just substitute the relevant citation command from `apacite`.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ref,
Author = {Garth Marenghi},
Date-Added = {2017-09-07 18:04:40 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2017-09-07 18:05:14 +0000},
Journal = {Expertise},
Number = {4},
Pages = {208},
Title = {Darkplace},
Volume = {38},
Year = {1988}}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\setlength\footnotemargin{10pt}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\NewDocumentCommand\footcite{ O{} O{} m }{%
  \footnote{\citet[#1][#2]{#3}.}%
}
\begin{document}
Generic text.\footcite{ref}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: possible footnote citation format]